# C++ Levelization and Dependency Analysis for Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, dependencies, refactoring

I have a C++ project with around 1700 source code files and headers where I'm trying to extract platform-independent classes for a cross-platform C++ dynamic library.

But there are terrible dependencies on platform-specific code all over the place, such that including even one file to satisfy the compiler leads to a half-dozen other files that need to be included.  A mess!

I'd like to visualize those dependencies in some way where I can make the most progress by rewriting/refactoring code to eliminate those dependencies.  I recall (years ago) a project I worked on used tools to "levelize" the source code to eliminate as many spurious dependencies and create a "clean" class hierarchy.

What are some tools for doing this?  Any suggestions for embarking on this process?

ADDITIONAL THOUGHT:  Can Doxygen be used for this purpose?